# Visual Studio for Mac / iPad Device - Waiting for debugger to connect

Tags: ipad, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am getting this error out of a sudden after not working on my Xamarin.Forms project for a while.  I havent seen it before and googling is not helping a lot

[image]

Comment: have you updated your device to iOS12?  If so, have you also updated XCode to the latest version?

Comment: @Jason Aha!  Yes, iOS is 12 but havent updated XCode.  I'll try that.  Much appreciated

Comment: @Jason Can you post that as an answer and I'll accept it.  This resolved my problem.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you updated your device to iOS12? If so, have you also updated XCode to the latest version?